# Better ways to manipulate classNames and handle clicks in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

New to React and JSX, and I am trying to wrap my head how to more elegantly, or efficiently, manipulate classes and manage click events. I'm working on two components (one of which that is getting quite large)–Greatlakes & InfoSide. In the Greatlakes component, I am trying to add classes to a series of different elements in a chart based on some of them being clicked. I have a working component here, but it's become way bloated with state booleans and then class determining state if/else statements in render().

My next move is to break out this Greatlakes component into some child components and look for ways to let the child click events affect the parent's state...any guidance would be very helpful.

```
import React from 'react'
import InfoSide from 'js/modules/InfoSide'

import 'stylesheets/modules/greatlakes.scss'

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return{
            clicked: false,
            keyClicked: false,
            aquaticClicked: false,
            pollutedClicked: false,
            federalClicked: false,
            fedSectionClicked: false,
            aquaSectionClicked: false,
            polSectionClicked: false,
            glriClicked: false,
            glcClicked: false,
            allianceClicked: false,
            nwfClicked: false
        };
    },
    handleAquaClick: function(){
        if(!this.state.aquaticClicked)this.setState({
            clicked: true,
            aquaticClicked:true, 
            pollutedClicked: false,
            federalClicked: false,
            glriClicked: false,
            fedSectionClicked: false,
            glcClicked: false,
            allianceClicked: false
        })
        else this.setState({aquaticClicked: false, clicked: false})
    },
    handlePollutedClick: function(){
        if(!this.state.pollutedClicked)this.setState({
            clicked: true,
            pollutedClicked:true, 
            aquaticClicked: false,
            federalClicked: false,
            glriClicked: false,
            fedSectionClicked: false,
            glcClicked: false,
            allianceClicked: false
        })
        else this.setState({pollutedClicked: false, clicked: false})
    },
    handleFederalClick: function(){
        if(!this.state.federalClicked)this.setState({
            clicked: true,
            federalClicked:true, 
            aquaticClicked: false,
            pollutedClicked: false,
            glriClicked: false,
            fedSectionClicked: false,
            glcClicked: false,
            allianceClicked: false
        })
        else this.setState({federalClicked: false, clicked: false})
    },
    handleGlriClick: function(){
        if(!this.state.glriClicked)this.setState({
            clicked: true,
            federalClicked:false, 
            aquaticClicked: false,
            pollutedClicked: false,
            glriClicked: true,
            fedSectionClicked: true,
            glcClicked: false,
            allianceClicked: false
        })
        else this.setState({federalClicked: false, glriClicked: false, fedSectionClicked: false, glcClicked: false, clicked: false})
    },
    handleGlcClick: function(){
        if(!this.state.glcClicked)this.setState({
            clicked: true,
            federalClicked:false, 
            aquaticClicked: false,
            pollutedClicked: false,
            glriClicked: false,
            fedSectionClicked: true,
            glcClicked: true,
            allianceClicked: false
        })
        else this.setState({federalClicked: false, glriClicked: false, fedSectionClicked: false, glcClicked: false, clicked: false})
    },
    handleAllianceClick: function(){
        if(!this.state.allianceClicked)this.setState({
            clicked: true,
            federalClicked:false, 
            aquaticClicked: false,
            pollutedClicked: false,
            glriClicked: false,
            fedSectionClicked: true,
            glcClicked: false,
            allianceClicked: true,
            aquaSectionClicked: true,
            polSectionClicked: true,

        })
        else this.setState({federalClicked: false, glriClicked: false, fedSectionClicked: false, glcClicked: false, allianceClicked: false, clicked: false})
    },
    handleNwfClick: function(){
        if(!this.state.allianceClicked)this.setState({
            clicked: true,
            federalClicked:false, 
            aquaticClicked: false,
            pollutedClicked: false,
            glriClicked: false,
            fedSectionClicked: true,
            glcClicked: false,
            allianceClicked: true,
            aquaSectionClicked: true,
            polSectionClicked: true,
            nwfClicked:true
        })
        else this.setState({federalClicked: false, glriClicked: false, fedSectionClicked: false, glcClicked: false, allianceClicked: false, nwfClicked:false, clicked: false})
    },
    handleKeyClick: function(){
        if(!this.state.keyClicked) this.setState({keyClicked:true});
        else this.setState({keyClicked: false})
    },
    render: function(){
        var glContentClick = this.state.clicked ? 'on' : '';
        var keyClick = this.state.keyClicked || this.state.allianceClicked || this.state.nwfClicked ? 'on' : '';
        var aq = this.state.aquaticClicked ? 'on' : '';
        var pol = this.state.pollutedClicked ? 'on' : '';
        var fed = this.state.federalClicked ? 'on' : '';
        var tierAq = this.state.aquaticClicked || this.state.aquaSectionClicked ? 'tier two on' : 'tier two';
        var tierPol = this.state.pollutedClicked || this.state.polSectionClicked ? 'tier two on' : 'tier two';
        var tierFed = this.state.federalClicked || this.state.fedSectionClicked ? 'tier two on' : 'tier two';
        var glri = this.state.glriClicked ? 'title on' : 'title';
        var glc = this.state.glcClicked ? 'title on' : 'title';
        var alliance = this.state.allianceClicked ? 'title on' : 'title';
        var nwf = this.state.nwfClicked ? 'title on' : 'title';

        return(
            <div className='greatlakes view'>
                <div className={'greatlakes-wrap '+glContentClick}>
                    <section className='intro'>
                        <h2>Great Lakes</h2>
                        <p>The Joyce Foundation seeks to protect and restore the Great Lakes by resolving the most critical basin-wide threats to the region’s water resources. The health and resilience of the Great Lakes may be significantly improved by simultaneously making progress on three interconnected issues: aquatic invasive species; runoff pollution, especially excess nutrients from cities and farms; and advancing and defending key state, regional, and federal policies and funding.</p>
                    </section>
                    <section className='key'>
                        <p className={keyClick} onClick={this.handleKeyClick}>View July 2016 Proposed Grants</p>
                    </section>
                    <section className='greatlakes-content'>
                        <h2 className='tier one'><span>Organizations Receiving Great Lakes Grant Payments in 2016</span></h2>
                        <div className={tierAq}>
                            <h3 onClick={this.handleAquaClick}><span>Aquatic Invasive Species</span></h3>
                            <ul className='tier three'>
                                <li className='title'><h4><span>Asian Carp</span></h4></li>
                                <li onClick={this.handleAllianceClick} className={keyClick}>Alliance for the Great Lakes</li>
                                <li>Freshwater Future</li>
                                <li>Great Lakes & St. Lawrence Cities Init.</li>
                                <li>Great Lakes Commission</li>
                                <li>NRDC</li>
                                <li onClick={this.handleNwfClick} className={keyClick}>NWF</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul className='tier three'>
                                <li className='title'><h4><span>Ballast Water</span></h4></li>
                                <li onClick={this.handleAllianceClick} className={keyClick}>Alliance for the Great Lakes</li>
                                <li>NRDC</li>
                                <li onClick={this.handleNwfClick} className={keyClick}>NWF</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className={tierPol}>
                            <h3 onClick={this.handlePollutedClick}><span>Poluted Runoff</span></h3>
                            <section className='tier three'>
                                <h4><span>Urban</span></h4>
                                <ul className='tier four'>
                                    <li className='title'><h5><span>Policy Solutions</span></h5></li>
                                    <li>CNT</li>
                                    <li>Metropolitan Planning Council</li>
                                    <li>State Advocates: <span className={keyClick}>OEC, MEC</span>, MEP, <span>Clean WI</span></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul className='tier four'>
                                    <li className='title'><h5><span>Pilots</span></h5></li>
                                    <li>Chi Cal Rivers Fund</li>
                                    <li>CNT</li>
                                    <li>SWWT</li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>
                            <section className='tier three'>
                                <h4><span>Agriculture</span></h4>
                                <ul className='tier four'>
                                    <li className='title'><h5><span>Policy Solutions</span></h5></li>
                                    <li onClick={this.handleAllianceClick} className={keyClick}>Alliance for the Great Lakes</li>
                                    <li>Freshwater Future</li>
                                    <li>Great Lakes Commission</li>
                                    <li>MI LCV Ed. Fund</li>
                                    <li onClick={this.handleNwfClick} className={keyClick}>NWF</li>
                                    <li>OSU StoneLab</li>
                                    <li>State Advocates: <span className={keyClick}>OEC, MEC</span>, MEP, <span>Clean WI</span></li>
                                    <li>US Water Alliance</li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul className='tier four'>
                                    <li className='title'><h5><span>Pilots</span></h5></li>
                                    <li>Environmental Defense Fund</li>
                                    <li>Nature Conservancy</li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div className={tierFed}>
                            <h3 onClick={this.handleFederalClick}><span>Federal & Regulated Policy</span></h3>
                            <ul className='tier three'>
                                <li onClick={this.handleGlriClick} className={glri}><h4><span>Great Lakes Restoration Initiative</span></h4></li>
                                <li onClick={this.handleAllianceClick} className={keyClick}>Alliance for the Great Lakes</li>
                                <li>Freshwater Future</li>
                                <li>Great Lakes & St. Lawrence Cities Init.</li>
                                <li>Great Lakes Commission</li>
                                <li>Healing Our Waters Coalition (NPCA, NWF)</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul className='tier three'>
                                <li onClick={this.handleGlcClick}  className={glc}><h4><span>Great Lakes Compact</span></h4></li>
                                <li onClick={this.handleAllianceClick} className={keyClick}>Alliance for the Great Lakes</li>
                                <li>NRDC</li>
                                <li onClick={this.handleNwfClick} className={keyClick}>NWF</li>
                                <li>State Advocates: <span className={keyClick}>OEC, MEC</span>, MEP, <span>Clean WI</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <InfoSide aquaClass={aq} pollutedClass={pol} fedClass={fed} glriClass={glri} glcClass={glc} allianceClass={alliance} nwfClass={nwf} infoClass={glContentClick} />
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

And Here is the Infoside component:

```
import React from 'react'
import 'stylesheets/modules/infoside.scss'

export default React.createClass({
  render:function(){
      return(
        <section id='info-side' className={'info-side '+this.props.infoClass}>
          <div className='info-side-wrap'>
            <p className={this.props.aquaClass}>Aquatic stuff here</p>
            <p className={this.props.pollutedClass}>Polluted stuff here</p>
            <p className={this.props.fedClass}>Federal stuff here</p>
            <p className={this.props.glriClass}>GLRI stuff here</p>
            <p className={this.props.glcClass}>GLC stuff here</p>
            <p className={this.props.allianceClass}>Alliance stuff here</p>
            <p className={this.props.nwfClass}>NWF stuff here</p>
          </div>
        </section>
      );
    }
})
```

Comment: I would take a look at some helper modules i.e. [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

Comment: Does this kind of manipulation go beyond the expected UI activity supported by react/react-dom?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```
var classNames = require('classnames');

var Button = React.createClass({
  // ... 
  render () {
    var btnClass = classNames({
      'btn': true,
      'btn-pressed': this.state.isPressed,
      'btn-over': !this.state.isPressed && this.state.isHovered
    });
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
});
```